# React state array indexing not possible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-props

I have a react component:

```
export default class Detail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: null,
      description: null,
      address: null,
      coordinates: null
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const apiUrl = `http://localhost:8000/api/frontend/listing/${
      this.props.match.params.id
    }`;
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response =>
        this.setState({
          name: response.name,
          description: response.description,
          address: response.address,
          coordinates: response.coordinates
        })
      );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MapComponent
          isMarkerShown
          googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
          loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
          coords={this.state.coordinates}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Which uses the following component:

```
const MapComponent = withScriptjs(
  withGoogleMap(props => (
    <GoogleMap
      defaultZoom={8}
      defaultCenter={{ lat: +props.coords[0], lng: +props.coords[1] }}
    >
      {props.isMarkerShown && (
        <Marker position={{ lat: +props.coords[0], lng: +props.coords[1] }} />
      )}
    </GoogleMap>
  ))
);
```

This fails to compile, with the error being

> Cannot read property '0' of null

when it tries to index the coords array. In order to debug this, I tried to remove the indexing (i.e. lat and lng both equal to props.coords). Obviously, this makes no sense logically, and the Google API complained, but react did not. Also, using the chrome react tools showed that props.coords does in fact exist, and is an array containing the two coordinates as expected. So why won't javascript let me index an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the array, the problem is that your data is fetched asynchronously. The `MapComponent` is rendered before the data has been fetched.

A common practice to handle these cases in React is to check the state in the render method and render a spinner or “please wait” message etc. as long as the data is being fetched.

When the data is available and the state is set with that data, the component will automatically render again, this time displaying the data.

Example:

```
export default class Detail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: null,
            description: null,
            address: null,
            coordinates: null
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const apiUrl = `http://localhost:8000/api/frontend/listing/${
            this.props.match.params.id
            }`;
        fetch(apiUrl)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(response =>
                this.setState({
                    name: response.name,
                    description: response.description,
                    address: response.address,
                    coordinates: response.coordinates
                })
            );
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.coordinates) {
            return <div>Fetching data, please wait…</div>;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <MapComponent
                    isMarkerShown
                    googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
                    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                    containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
                    mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
                    coords={this.state.coordinates}
                />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the React component lifecycle, render is called before componentDidMount.

This means that the first time render is called, this.state.coordinates is null and therefore has no 0 index.

Change your constructor to set coordinates to be an empty array.
e.g.

```
this.state = {
  name: null,
  description: null,
  address: null,
  coordinates: []
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A concrete solution would be like.

The reason you get `Cannot read property '0' of null` because you have initialized coordinates with null value so on your component initial render you are sending coordinates null to the MapComponent and accessing the data. So make coordinates with empty array and do conditional checks and then render.

You need to take care of loading the message to user, when you receive success response you need to stop showing loading message and render the response like wise you also need to show error message to the user if fetch api call fails. In the below code the conditional checks does all these

The functionality should work always so you need to take care of resetting state values so that it works every time your component newly renders with showing loading or success response or error response if fetch fails

The below code explains in detail with concrete solution

```
export default class Detail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: null,
      description: null,
      address: null,
      coordinates: [],
      error: null
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
       loading: true,
       name: null,
      description: null,
      address: null,
      coordinates: [],
      error: null
    });
    const apiUrl = `http://localhost:8000/api/frontend/listing/${
      this.props.match.params.id
    }`;
    fetch(apiUrl)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response =>
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          name: response.name,
          description: response.description,
          address: response.address,
          coordinates: response.coordinates,
          error: ""
        })
      )
      .catch(err =>
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          name: null,
          description: null,
          address: null,
          coordinates: [],
          error: "Error occurred while fetching data"
        })
      );
  }

  render() {
    const { coordinates, error, loading } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {loading && <div>Fetching data, please wait</div>}
        {!loading && coordinates.length == 0 && <div>{error}</div>}
        {!loading && error == null && coordinates.length > 0 && (
        <MapComponent
          isMarkerShown
          googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places"
          loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
          containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
          coords={coordinates}
          />)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```